# jQuery if width is less then.. change src attr, else, use the previous

Tags: jquery, image, if-statement, src, attr

(sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand)
I would like that when the window `width` is less than `601px` the `src` attribute of the image with `.logo-wrap` container became `#`; and when the width is larger the `src attr` returned as the "original"; The first part of the code works, but after I scale down the window and then carry it larger the src attribut remains `#`...

Any suggestions?
thanks in advance

```
var $window = $(window);

function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize < 601) {
        $(".logo-wrap img").attr("src","#");
    }
    else {}
}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Comment: you may use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $window = $(window);

// creates an attribute called data-content for each image and stores it's src
$(".logo-wrap img").each(function() {
  $(this).data('data-content', $(this).attr('src'));
});

function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize < 601) {
        $(".logo-wrap img").attr("src","#");
    }
    else {
      // changes each image's src to the link stored in data-content attribute
      $(".logo-wrap img").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data('data-content'));
      });
    }
}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Edit: Added [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9r3335g/7/).

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to try to do so but I thought that by wirting the variable it would have taken anyway the "#"
Thanks you!

Comment: No problem. As long as you save the attribute before changing it, it will remain the original one. You can accept the answer if everything works good now.

Comment: Unfortunately looking well I saw that it creates problems...
I have more `.Logo-wrap` containers with image inside; so when I make it larger the script copy the src attribute of the first image to all of the other images :-/ have you any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to use this on one or all of the images? Could you show the html?

Comment: I need to use `#` for all the images when width is less than 601px and each different `src` attribute of the various images when the window is larger. [here an example of HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/x9r3335g/)

Comment: I edited my answer and now it should do it for every image.

Answer (score 0):

IT looks like you're just not changing the attribute back,

```
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize < 601) {
        $(".logo-wrap img, .lab-ah img").attr("src","#");
    }
    else if ( windowsize >= 601) {
        $(".logo-wrap img, .lab-ah img").attr("src","original");
    }
}
```

I hope i understood your question correctly